# get value from ActiveRecord CollectionProxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to get value from an ActiveRecord CollectionProxy.

(I am new to rails, this might be a simple question but is very confusing for me.)

I am trying this to get the value:

```
MedicalTest.last.testing_center.users
```

The response I get from this is:

#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<User id: 125, first_name: "QAQA", last_name: "XXXX", email: "aqeek1@gmail.com", role: "testing_chain_coordinator", created_at: "2021-06-15 05:28:34.568698000 +0000", updated_at: "2021-06-15 05:28:34.568698000 +0000", resourceable_type: "TestingChain", resourceable_id: 52>]>

I am trying to get each email using this:

```
MedicalTest.last.testing_center.users.collect(&:email)
```

It returns an array of emails and not the value

How can I get each value?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by _"returns an array of emails and not the value"_. What value if not a list of users' emails do you expect instead?

Comment: Do you need to iterate over the emails array like this? `MedicalTest.last.testing_center.users.pluck(:email).each {|email| puts email }`

Comment: An example of exactly what you expect "value" to look like would help. I am only guessing also, but is it possible that `MedicalTest.last.testing_center.users.collect(&:attributes)` is what you are looking for?

Comment: An example type and display for "value" would help us better understand what you want returned about the collection of users.

Answer (score 0):

`collect(&:email)` will collect all emails for the collection and will return the array of email values for each record in that collection.

In case you want to do something extra and to see maybe more info, you should do the following:

```
  MedicalTest.last.testing_center.users.collect{|user| {id: user.id, email: user.email } }
```

In your case, this will return => `[{id: 125, email: "aqeek1@gmail.com"}]`

Then you can iterate through the result array and do additional actions.